# Continuous function with zero integral

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ ($a<b$), such that $\int_{a}^{b}{f(t)dt}=0$

Show that $\exists c\in[a,b], f(c)=0$.

Comment: Rolle's theorem!

Comment: $$ \min_{a\le x\le b} f(x) \le\textstyle{1\over b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\le  \max_{a\le x\le b} f(x).$$ So, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, for some $c\in[a,b]$, $f(c)={1\over b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the function
$$
F(x):=\int_a^xf(t)dt
$$
is continuous on $[a,b]$ with derivative $F'=f$ on $(a,b)$.

Now $F(a)=F(b)=0$.

By Rolle, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $F'(c)=f(c)=0$.

Comment: Nice. To use Rolle's theorem, one must also note that F is differentiable on ]a,b[.

Comment: I changed my mind and finally chose your answer instead of Amr's. This is because Amr's solution requires the study of many cases : $m=M=0$, $m<0,M>0$ etc.

Comment: @Bear Yes, I said "with derivative $F'=f$ on $(a,b)$. Doesn't this mean that $F$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$?

Comment: you are right ;)

Answer (score 3):

Let $m=\min\{f(x)|x\in[a,b]\}, m=\max\{f(x)|x\in[a,b]\}$(We can get the minimum and maximum because $f$ is continuous on a closed interval) . If $m,M$ have the same sign it can be shown that the integral cant be zero (for example if both are positive, the the integral will be positive). If $m,M$ have different signs apply the intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 1):

Proceed by contradiction: assume that $f(x)\not=0$ for all $a\le x\le b$. Then either $f(x)>0$ for all $a\le x\le b$, or $f(x)<0$ for all $a\le x\le b$. Because, if there existed $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$ with $f(x_1)<0<f(x_2)$, then, by the intermediate value theorem, we would have a $c$ such that $f(c)=0$.

In the first case let $d=\inf\{f(x);a\le x\le b\}=\min\{f(x);a\le x\le b\}$ ($d$ is a minimum because $f$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is compact. Furthermore $d>0$), therefore $\int_a^bf(t)dt\ge d(b-a)>0$, which contradicts our assumption.

The second case is similar.

Comment: $f(x)\not=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ dos not imply that f(x)>0 for all x or f(x)<0 is negative for all x

Comment: For example $f$ might be positive for some x in [a,b] and negative for the rest

Comment: @Amr it does for continuous functions, by IVT

Comment: @JanDvorak true. But this should be mentioned.

Comment: Yes, UweF, nicely written, +1. I don't understand why somebody downvoted.

Comment: Given the discussion, I find it amusing that @Amr omitted from his answer the part this one elaborates upon.

Comment: Nice too ! Thanks.

Comment: After seeing the discussion that occured while I was not here , @Hurkyl,  I wanted to say that I did not downvote anybody, plus I don't think my solution is the only correct one. The reason why I said that IVT should be mentioned is because I think that it was not clear the way it was mentioned (I found it not clear the first time I read it until Jan Dvorak) pointed this out. Conclusion: The reason I suggested why IVT should be mentioned is only because I thought it was not clear thats all.

Comment: @Julien and I did not down vote anybody!